# Installing OS X on new SSD with 10.8 found online

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ssd

Since I had lost the CDs that came with my MacBook Pro (late 2010/11 model – 10.6 OS X CDs) I couldn't continue with my OS X installation. I asked Apple about purchasing the CDs but it would take over 2 months for them to arrive :/ (I can't wait that long as I use it for work.)

I have found a version of "Mac OS X 10.7 Lion (Final Retail)" online but it's only 3.5 GB. Is it a logical size of the OS files to be that "little"? I remember OS 10.6 was like 6 GB+.

If I went on and burned that dmg file to a disk would I be able to install Mac OS X or is "Mac OS X 10.7 Lion (Final Retail) - 3.5 GB" a patch file and I would need the operating system to be already installed?

What I am worried about is the reliability of the uploader of this file and if he has tampered with it.

Comment: A friendly reminder that pirated software is off topic. As long as this stays with how to verify a download, I don't see a need for closing this, but we might want to discuss on [meta] and close this if the community feels it's out of bounds based on the [help].

Answer (score 1):

Use the checksum to validate the integrity of the file.

Sometimes when you download large files, the host will provide an MD5 checksum, which is a hash of the raw file data that you can use to compare and see if any of the data was corrupted, changed, or lost during the download process.

To verify the MD5SUM in OS X, simply open the Terminal and type “md5″ followed by one space, and then drag and drop the downloaded file from the finder into the terminal window.

Hit return on your keyboard and wait a few moments (The larger the file, the longer it will take).

The terminal will spit out the MD5 hash for the file, which you can then compare to the once provided by the download originator!

Comment: Good idea, I will try to find the hash of the original version and compare the two.

If I burn the version Mac OS X 10.7 Lion (Final Retail) dmg file on a dvd will I be able to isntall mac os x on my mbp?

Comment: This won't help unless you're getting the original hash from someone else (like Apple), if you're concerned with the scruples of the vendor and not just errors in transit.

Answer (score 0):

An OS X Lion dmg of 3.5GB seems right because in 10.7 Apple removed all 32-bit support, and this saved a lot of space. Of course that doesn't guarantee the that your file is good. You might try to check the hash as Buscar mentioned.

To write the dmg file in Windows, you can either convert it with [dmg2img](http://vu1tur.eu.org/tools/) if you know how to use the command prompt, or burn it immediately to a disk (or better: "restore" it to a usb stick) using [TransMac](http://www.acutesystems.com/scrtm.htm) (unrestricted 15-day trial).

Answer (score 0):

You can check with a public list of Apple installation media checksums (SHA1): https://github.com/notpeter/apple-installer-checksums#verify-checksums

Example for checking on Linux:

```
sha1sum "Mac OS X Lion.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg"
```

In the case of Lion the result should be `a044fc01fa75b1f255dbdd6ea4fefa30cef147b0`.

Comment: How is this better than getting the installer and verifying it from Apple? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202369

Comment: @bmike: a question that contains yet another good answer. It is not better, but different: installer can be checked on any machine, not on the Mac only.